# How to calculate a point N lines from another point in elisp?

Tags: motion

Given a point, how can I get the point *N* lines before/after it?

---

*Will post own answer, but I'm not sure it's optimal.*

Comment: Yes, using `save-excursion` and motion (go there and get `point`) is what is used. Some motion functions are more efficient than others. `forward-line` is efficient, for example.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using `save-excursion`, then moving the cursor.

```lisp
(defun point-calc-lines-offset (pt lines)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char pt)
    (forward-line lines)
    (point))
```

Comment: Turns our this is how to do it, thanks @Drew.